# Angular project build fail only on GitHub Actions

Tags: angular, npm, github-actions

I'm having a weird problem where suddenly GitHub Action workflow is failing compiling an Angular project, while it still works on my (and my peers) local machine. Note I'm running `npm ci` and not `npm install`.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-eslint/schematics@13.2.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cli@14.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/cli@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cli@">= 13.0.0 < 14.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@13.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!   dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"^13.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/cli@13.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cli@">= 13.0.0 < 14.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@13.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-eslint/schematics
npm ERR!     dev @angular-eslint/schematics@"^13.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/runner/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-06-09T16_17_41_426Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And this is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --source-map=false",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration walabot-home",
    "dev": " ng serve --configuration walabothome-app-cloud"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.41",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.9",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.22.8",
    "firebase": "^9.8.2",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.43",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "luxon": "^2.4.0",
    "openapi-typescript-codegen": "^0.23.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "2.3.2"
  }
}
```

The CI workflow:

```yaml
name: Dashboard

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      project-id:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version-file: ".nvmrc"
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: package-lock.json
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build -- --configuration=${{ inputs.project-id }}
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: dashboard-dist
          path: dashboard/dist
```

Edit: things are still broken when downgrading to Angular CLI 13:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: angular2-csv@0.2.9
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"14.0.1" from @angular/material@14.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from angular2-csv@0.2.9
npm ERR! node_modules/angular2-csv
npm ERR!   angular2-csv@"^0.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@6.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from angular2-csv@0.2.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular2-csv
npm ERR!     angular2-csv@"^0.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/runner/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-06-09T17_31_14_082Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As walid said, just downgrade the Angular cli:

```
devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "13.0.0",
```

Maybe 13 will work for you.

Edit:
For future visitors, see this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4998

Comment: That still doesn't work. Can't really understand why...

Comment: I think this discussion on GitHub might helps you: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4998

Comment: That explains a lot - thanks! This is the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your dependencies do not like your recent CLI upgrade to Angular 14. Try to downgrade your CLI version or use `--force` flag when you `ng update`.

As stated  [in the Angular Doc](https://angular.io/cli/update)

> [--force] Ignore peer dependency version mismatches. Passes the
> '--force' flag to the package manager when installing packages.

Comment: The problem is that I do not see that error on any machine (or NodeJS container image), so I cannot understand where the problem lies exactly. How do I downgrade?